# Use Ninject.Wcf in ASP.NET MVC3. Deriving from NinjectWcfApplication disables application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, ninject, ninject-extensions

I am using AJAX-enable web services in my ASP.NET MVC3 application and I want to inject some classes in to them. So I installed NInject.Wcf, set factory to  `Ninject.Extensions.Wcf.NinjectServiceHostFactory` and next step is derive application class(`MVCApplication` in Global.asax) from `NinjectWcfApplication`, but when I have done this, IIS stopped to run my application, it tries to use StaticFile module rather than route request to controller.

How to fix this or how to implement NInject with WCF in other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out it, the reason why routes has not been setup correctly is because of default Global.asax template for ASP.NET MVC application, by default it defines

```
void Application_Start() { ... }
```

and since HttpApplication don't have this method defined IIS call this method on start up. So when deriving from `NinjectWcfApplication` which **have** defined Application_Start method, we need to change default method to:

```
protected override void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    .....
    base.Application_Start(sender, e);
}
```

if we don't do this IIS will call `NinjectWcfApplication.Application_Start` instead of our `Application_Start` method.